# How can I query a SharePoint list using InfoPath 2010 and return a value that matches the input parameters?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

In excel I created a prototype of a record search tool.There are three parameters to select. Based on the selection the excel formula runs through a table and identifies the rows where all three parameters are true, and return a particular cell. Essentially, it is a database search. I can't provide the data due to confidentiality, however, it's really the functionality that is important here.

Now that I've proven the logic of the system and shown that it returns the values I'm looking for, the next step is to take the logic and recreate this search tool in infopath 2010. The data that it will search through will reside in a SharePoint list (data source).

However, the formulas in infopath 2010 don't seem to be as straight forward as in excel. Although I'm able to make the data connections and create the drop downs for selecting the parameters, I'm struggling to recreate the database search functionality.

The infopath form needs to take the three parameters, query the SharePoint list, and return the value (within the same form) that matches those three parameters. Is this possible in infopath 2010? How so? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up a data connection to the list, and it's an ordinary list, then querying it should be very simple.

The list data connection should have a group called queryFields with a field for each of the columns in the list. All you need to do is use **Set a field's value** rules to copy your query values into the respective fields, and then use a rule to execute the query. Have you tried that?

Comment: Relatively new to InfoPath so had to go back and do some reading. After reading about query fields, data fields, and buttons I was able to run the expected queries. Thank you!